# Is there a way to find the class is a test class?

Tags: apex, dml

I am looking for simple solution to find he class is a test class , Other than checking body contains @isTest ?

i have checked the below URL but there are no options ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm

Comment: Why isn't just checking for '@isTest' the easiest way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SOSL query to find your test classes. Note that this is not foolproof, as SOSL doesn't differentiate between comments and non-comments

```
ApexClass[] unitTests = [FIND '@isTest' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Id, Name)][0];
```

[How to get a list of Test Classes in an org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122870/how-to-get-a-list-of-test-classes-in-an-org)

else, You can go to "`Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution`". There you can press on the button "Select Tests...", this will list all the current test classes in your org.