# Fetching all Testclasses only from un manage package

Tags: soql, sql

Query: `Select id from apexclass where class name like '%test%'`.

Above query if fetching both managed and unmanaged package classes, can i filter only unmanaged package.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/122870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by the namespace prefix. Assuming your org is not a developer org:

```
SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = NULL AND Name LIKE '%Test%'
```

Alternatively, I prefer to use SOSL, so I don't accidentally pick up files that have Test in the name but are not actual tests:

```
FIND '@isTest' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Id WHERE NamespacePrefix = NULL)
```