# Dynamically query @AuraEnabled Apex Class

Tags: apex, aura

For one of the requirements, I need to query and list down Apex class those are only `@AuraEnabled` in nature. Is there any Metadata API is available for this?

I believe this is not going to help me...

`ApexClass classNameList = [SELECT Body FROM ApexClass]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@AuraEnabled` annotation is not available for a class, but the [only available for static methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm).
But if you want to obtain a list of Apex Classes with `@AuraEnabled` methods you can evolve your approach this way:

```java
List<ApexClass> apexClasses = [
        SELECT Name, Body
        FROM ApexClass
        /* WHERE Status = 'Active' */
];
List<String> classesNamesWithAuraEnabledMethods = new List<String>();
for (ApexClass apexClass: apexClasses) {
    if (apexClass.Body.contains('@AuraEnabled')) {
        classesNamesWithAuraEnabledMethods.add(apexClass.Name);
    }
}
// desired list of classes with @AuraEnabled methods
System.debug(classesNamesWithAuraEnabledMethods);
```

This is a basic example that doesn't cover all the scenarios (for instance if your `@AuraEnabled` method is commented) but you can write your own filter rules dealing only with apex class body string representation.

**UPDATE:** You can also use `SOSL` query to find all `@AuraEnabled` classes just like in [@sfdxfox answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122870/how-to-get-a-list-of-test-classes-in-an-org/122872#122872):

```java
List<ApexClass> classesWithAuraEnabledMethods = [
        FIND '@IsTest' 
        IN ALL FIELDS 
        RETURNING ApexClass(Id, Name)
][0];
```

But using that approach you should also keep in mind that according to the [Apex Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) the max total number of records retrieved by a single `SOSL` query is `2000`.

Comment: FYI, SOSL can find those classes without querying all classes to find the values; see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/122872/2984) where i suggest that to find test classes.