# SOQL query to filter ApexClass based on the InstalledPackage

Tags: soql

I am working on a task to retrieve test classes filtered on the basis of package that they are part of. I am trying to run the below query to do so but gets error when trying to filter on the basis of InstalledPackage.

> sfdx force:data:soql:query --query="SELECT Id,Name,SymbolTable FROM ApexClass WHERE InstalledPackage = 'XYZ'" --usetoolingapi --targetusername=myorg --json | jq '.result.records[] | select(.SymbolTable != null) | select(.SymbolTable.methods[].annotations[].name == "IsTest")' | jq '.Name' | uniq

Error:

```
"status": 1,
  "name": "INVALID_FIELD",
  "message": "\nSymbolTable FROM ApexClass WHERE InstalledPackage = ''\n
             ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:49\nNo such column 'InstalledPackage' on entity 'ApexClass'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
```

[image: image of Salesforce UI]

Could you please let me know if I need to update the query or there is any other way to retrieve test classes filtered based on package.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. Also, just in case, please read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), which may be relevant here. You can't query based on the Installed Package field, which is a type of "fake field," but depending on your "X" (from above), there might be another way to get the information you need. You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Done, I believe I've now added all the information that maybe required.

Comment: Where are you getting your schema from for ApexClass? I don't see InstalledPackage listed anywhere as a field you can query.  Or are you guessing that it's the field you're after?

Comment: @NickCook I found the similar query and trying to use after adding it a WHERE clause. Is their any issue in syntax? or else is their any other way to fulfill the requirement?

Comment: @Ashwani But where did you find the 'similar query'? is it in official docs? If not, how do you know if it works for whoever wrote it?

Comment: @NickCook I found the query here
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122870/how-to-get-a-list-of-test-classes-in-an-org

Comment: @NickCook

I am trying to import test suites name/id from Salesforce.

Since Salesforce may include a large number of test suites - we would like to allow the user to import test suites from a specific package/folder.

Is there a way for retrieving test suites of a specific Salesforce package ( managed as well as unmanaged )

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but the following might work:

> SELECT Id, Name, NamespacePrefix FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = 'XYZ'

To find out what fields you can query on any object, you can use the Developer Console.

e.g.

[image]

Where you can clearly see the fields you can add to your query, rather than just guessing based on the UI.

[image]
If not, please be clearer in your question about what you're after.

Comment: This was the similar query that I found and after looking at the Salesforce UI, I added 'InstalledPackage' field. I am new to Salesforce not much aware with the internals of Salesforce. Maybe the query is not working but at least from the initial lines, you must have got that I am trying to retrieve test apex classes of a particular package.

Comment: @Ashwani It is possible, you can go to Installed Packages, find the necessary package, copy its namespace prefix and run query: `SELECT Id, Name, NamespacePrefix FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = 'package_namespace_prefix'`

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova it will work if apply filter on NamespacePrefix but we need to apply filter on package name. What happens if we have 2 package with same namespace?

Comment: @NickCook Thanks for the analysis and showing fields that can be queried. Now, could you suggest if their is any other way to do the task?

Comment: @Ashwani You do not need any other approach. For 1 namespace there os only 1 Managed Package. If the Apex class is from Unmanaged Package, Installed Package in Apex Classes List View will be empty.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova

I am trying to import test suites name/id from Salesforce.

Since Salesforce may include a large number of test suites - we would like to allow the user to import test suites from a specific package/folder.

Is there a way for retrieving test suites of a specific Salesforce package ( managed as well as unmanaged )

Thanks