# Get Test Apex Classes of a specific package in Salesforce

Tags: test-automation

I am trying to import test suites name/id from Salesforce.

Since Salesforce may include a large number of test suites - we would like to allow the user to import test suites from a specific package/folder.

Is there a way for retrieving test suites of a specific Salesforce package ( managed as well as unmanaged )

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific in your question about what you're trying to achieve.  This question looks the same as your previous question, except you've removed your code.  How is it different from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122870/how-to-get-a-list-of-test-classes-in-an-org?

Comment: @NickCook The query I provided you was from the same page. The question asked there is partially similar to my requirements but I need something more. As per Maria's suggestion, we can implement this requirement on the basis of namespace prefix but since unmanaged packages don't mandatorily need to have namespace-prefix, how we'll be able to filter out them?

I simply need mechanism by which I can retrieve id/name of test classes by filtering on the basis of package they are part of regardless managed, unmanaged or created by user... Please let me know if there is any way I can achieve this.